# Efficiency when merging 2 tables and moving the result to another schema

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, merge, schema

I have 2 tables. One having 1 million rows (**Table 1**), and another having 99 million rows (**Table 2**). Both of them are in a separate schemas. 
They have similar structures, so no problem there.

My question would be this:

I need the table containing both of the tables' Data on the schema containing **Table 1**.

Would it be faster to run a code to transfer all 99 million rows of **Table 2** to **Table 1**

OR

Would it be faster to run a code to transfer all 1 million rows to **Table 2**, and then run a code to Alter **Table 2's** schema to **Table 1's** schema?

OR

Would everything actually be instantaneous?

Comment: Huh??? Are you wanting to end up with one table that is 100 million rows? Of course it would be round 98 times faster to move 1 million rows instead of 99 million rows. And no, this is not going to be instantaneous. You have to first read, then write, then delete 1 million rows. Or you could chose to do this with 99 million rows. The real answer of course is why haven't you tried this yourself on a test server?

Comment: @SeanLange this is just a thought experiment, I'm still learning and was just curious. It ~would be useful once I get in to it, tho. 
Another question from me to you would be: The altering of a table's schema is instantaneous, right? It's not as if it's moving the data physically, it just renames the schema parameter/variable or whatever, right?

Comment: No, altering the schema of a table is not instant. If you change datatypes it has to convert all the rows to the new storage format and possibly reindex and such. You would also want to do some maintenance after to help minimize page splits and that sort of thing.  Also any schema changes must be logged to maintain atomicity.

Comment: Thank you! That helps a lot. I understand more now.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you want to insert all records from Table 2 into Table 1. If this is the case I would suggest dropping the indexes on table 1, run the insert and then rebuild it. Alternatively you could leave the indexes on, but that would slow things WAY DOWN. Another solution which is my preferred, is create Table 3, insert each of the 2 tables into it, build the index then rename Table 1 & 2 to TableName_Backup, and rename table 3 to be whatever you want. The 2nd solution should give you optimal results while keep both original tables in their original state while you validate the data. Once you feel good, either put the 2 original tables in an archive location or drop them, depending on your company policy.

Comment: But wouldn't that take longer? 
Given that now I'd have to transfer 100m rows of Data?

And I don't only want to insert all rows of Table 2 into Table 1. 
I have 2 possible procedures we could do, and asked which of the 2 would be optimal. Schema is involved as well, table 1 and 2 are in different schemas.

We would consider what you gave us, tho. Thanks.
Having a backup is always helpful.